# How to represent a variable nested list in Go

Tags: list, go, nested-lists

How is a list such as:

```
{{1,2}, 3, {5, 6, 7}, 8, 9}
```

represented in Go? I need to be able to pass a nested variable size list to a function in Go from the main function. This list will then be processed inside the function by accessing the individual elements/sublists of the list.
Note that the size of the list and the sizes of sublists are variable.

Answer (score 6):

You have two basic choices:

First, you can make a slice of slices:

```
a := [][]int{
    []int{1,2},
    []int{3},
    []int{5, 6, 7},
    []int{8},
    []int{9},
}
```

This isn't quite what you wanted, but it is close. In this case single items are represented as a slice with one item. Simple.

Second, you can make a slice of `interface{}` and use type switches to identify and unpack each index:

```
b := []interface{}{
    []int{1,2},
    3,
    []int{5, 6, 7},
    8,
    9,
}
```

This is much more complicate to work with, but is also much closer to what you want.

Example of reading items from slice `b`:

```
// Note that things can get a lot more complicated if you have
// more types and/or you nest deeper than one level.
for _, iv := range b {
    switch v := iv.(type) {
    case []int:
        // v is an int slice
    case int:
        // v is an int
    default:
        // This will probably be an error case.
    }
}
```

I recomend you stick with the first method unless you have a really good reason not to.

Comment: Btw, `a := [][]int{{1, 2}, {3}, {5, 6, 7}}` <- this syntax also works

Comment: Depends on what version of go you are using. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: Hmm. 1.0 certainly wouldn't, but I don't remember when that change was added.

Comment: Right. I seriously wouldn't expect somebody to claim the go v1.0 support.

Comment: No, wait. I was wrong. Go 1.0 added that for pointer types in slices, 1.5 added support for maps. In any case it has been supported for a long time, I just haven't bothered to change :P

Comment: Thanks @Milo. I was looking for the second option, where you use an interface.The function that receives it as an argument does not know the slice size and if it contains another slice inside it. So, the second option is what it will have to use.